# UE5.2.1 crashes when calling a function from a Firebase plugin to read, write, listen to the database

Tags: firebase, plugins, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I just recently bought the plugin a couple of days ago and everything worked great.
[Firebase Blueprint Plugin Library](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/firebase-blueprint-plugin-library)

Authentication, queries to the Firestore database, and cloud storage worked until today.

But at one point, when testing Firestore requests and launching a game in the project, UE5 simply crashed and closed. Now queries and listening don’t work.

The plugin worked well for two days and stopped working today. UE5 simply crashes when the game starts if the Request or listen should be done in “EventBeginPlay”, or “EventConstruct”. And if you put the Firestore request launch on the button, then the game will start and when you press the button, both the game and UE5 will launch.

Authentication still works fine, for some reason only queries and database listening stopped working.

In the Visual Studio log I saw such an error just before the fall of UE5, and only when calling any functions from your plugin, except authentication

```
[2023-12-12T02:22:52.754Z]LogJson: Warning: Field firebase_url was not found.

[2023-12-12T02:22:52.754Z]LogJson: Error: Json Value of type 'Null' used as a 'String'.

An exception was thrown at 0x00007FFBB5AEC2CD (UnrealEditor-FBP.dll) in UnrealEditor.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBB5AEC2CD (UnrealEditor-FBP.dll) in UnrealEditor.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
```

I checked Cloud Storage - Download File, it also works fine, the files are downloaded.

Adding or editing documents also does not work.

Problems only with Firestore DataBase, with recording, listening, adding, editing.

The project was rebuilt, new empty projects were created, and the UE files were checked.
Everything is fine with the database, it has been working fine for a year now, but in other applications.

For the plugin to work you need to download google-services.json and place it in your project folder
But google-services.json works! Authentication, cloud storage is working. The BP database functions simply stopped working.
The Firestore database and Firebase itself have also been working great for over a year in other non-UE applications. I also wrote a development on Github, I’m just not sure that he will answer or at least answer in the near future

I also opened the plugin files, there is not a single json there. I opened the .h .cpp files, tried to find at least one mention of the firebase_url line there and also didn’t find anything

The error remains, I ask you for help, I no longer know what the problem could be.
The most interesting thing is that the plugin worked at first, I made about 10-15 test queries and database listens.